# EF6 Seed Data Incorrect on first pass

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

I am using EF6 code first to push my model to a database. Everything is working great in terms of creating the database and it does execute the seed commands as expected. The problem is that some of the seeds that are placed in my database on the first run of update-database command are incorrect. A subsequent run of update-database will correctly update the seeds to their expected values.

I have done the following:

- Removed the migrations folder and reset the migrations.
- Deleted my code base, and pulled a fresh copy from source control.
- Tried the update-database command from different machines with the same results.

Any Suggestions?

Updates:

Here is my model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using CustomerPortal.Website.Models.Enums;

namespace CustomerPortal.Website.Models
{
[Table("Document")]
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DocumentUID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentType")]
    [Required]
    public int DocumentTypeUID { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string DocumentToken { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FormNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool SendToParticipant { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool RequiresTransformation { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public DocumentTypeCode DocumentTypeCode
    {
        get { return (DocumentTypeCode)DocumentTypeUID; }
        set { DocumentTypeUID = (int)value; }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my DBMigrationsConfiguration

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using CustomerPortal.Website.DAL;

namespace CustomerPortal.Website.Migrations
{
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
        }

        internal class CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
        {
            protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
            {
                SetCreatedUtcColumn(addColumnOperation.Column);

                base.Generate(addColumnOperation);
            }

            protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
            {
                SetCreatedUtcColumn(createTableOperation.Columns);

                base.Generate(createTableOperation);
            }

            private static void SetCreatedUtcColumn(IEnumerable<ColumnModel> columns)
            {
                foreach (var columnModel in columns)
                {
                    SetCreatedUtcColumn(columnModel);
                }
            }

            private static void SetCreatedUtcColumn(PropertyModel column)
            {
                if (column.Name == "CreatedOnDate" || column.Name == "UpdatedOnDate")
                {
                    column.DefaultValueSql = "GETUTCDATE()";
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            SeedProcess.SeedDatabase(context);
        }
    }
    }
```

Here is my SeedProcess Class:

```
using CustomerPortal.Website.DAL.Seeds;
namespace CustomerPortal.Website.DAL
{
    public class SeedProcess
    {
        public static void SeedDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            DocumentTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            SiteImageTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            SubscriptionTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            DocumentEntityTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            StateTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            PaymentTransactionTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            PayerTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            BenefitPayoutTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            BillingFrequencyTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            CriteriaExpressionTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            FamilyCoverageTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            InstitutionTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            PaymentTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            ProductEnrollmentTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            ProductTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            ProductRateTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            BenefitTypeSeeds.Seed(context);
            PotentialEnrolleeStatusTypeSeeds.Seed(context);

            //Image and Document Seeds
            SiteImageSeeds.Seed(context);
            DocumentSeeds.Seed(context);

            //Base Product & Setup Seeds
            InstitutionSeeds.Seed(context);
            ProductSeeds.Seed(context);
            BenefitSeeds.Seed(context);
            ProductBenefitSeeds.Seed(context);
            OfferSeeds.Seed(context);
            PlanSeeds.Seed(context);
            PlanProductBenefitSeeds.Seed(context);
            PlanCoverageSeeds.Seed(context);
            PlanCoverageRateSeeds.Seed(context);
            CriteriaGroupSeeds.Seed(context);
            CriteriaSeeds.Seed(context);
            CriteriaGroupCriteriaSeeds.Seed(context);
            RoleSeeds.Seed(context);
            UserSeeds.Seed(context);

            //Customer Specific Offer Seeds
            FormGroupSeeds.Seed(context);
            FormGroupFormSeeds.Seed(context);
            InstitutionOfferGroupSeeds.Seed(context);
            InstitutionOfferGroupOfferSeeds.Seed(context);
            InstitutionOfferGroupPaymentOptionSeeds.Seed(context);


            //Seed Document Relations
            InstitutionDocumentSeeds.Seed(context);
            InstitutionOfferGroupDocumentSeeds.Seed(context);
            PlanCoverageDocumentSeeds.Seed(context);
            ProductDocumentSeeds.Seed(context);
            ProductStateDocumentSeeds.Seed(context);
            ProductMarketableStateSeeds.Seed(context);

        }
    }
}
```

And Finally here is the DocumentSeed class that doesnt seed correctly:

```
using CustomerPortal.Website.DAL;
using CustomerPortal.Website.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace CustomerPortal.Website.DAL.Seeds
{
public static class DocumentSeeds
{
    public static void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Documents.AddOrUpdate(
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 1,
            DocumentTypeUID = 2,
            DocumentToken = "834cc814-1321-4ef3-8bcd-5de0c66b71e7",
            DocumentName = "Crescent Medical Setup Doc.docx",
            FormNumber = "N/A",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = false,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        },
        //This is the problem seed. 
        //DocumentUID 2 should be the welcome letter
        //But on intial seed, its a privacy policy, which is actually Document UID 39
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 2,
            DocumentTypeUID = 3,
            DocumentToken = "af9b59e3-0270-45f4-ae7c-eb03602fc049",
            DocumentName = "Crescent Medical Welcome Letter",
            FormNumber = "N/A",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 3,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "2f7f6ba0-c9ee-47f0-af6c-7672a536e7e1",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 1 Family 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-1F",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 4,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "d00b8f58-2229-4206-a759-06eb764f493f",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 1 Single + 1 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-1 S1",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 5,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "17e346c9-0abd-4d14-bb21-124fe15649e7",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 1 Single 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-1S",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 6,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "29c0391a-f657-49b1-9692-842d97dc1517",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 2 Family 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-2F",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 7,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "1cfd5698-9b23-48e5-9096-30d007a395f6",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 2 Single + 1 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-2 S1",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 8,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "b46f2716-aed9-4096-950f-6a7374bc7961",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 2 Single 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-2S",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 9,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "815d0259-636a-4d1f-9d8e-6a55e2fb3463",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 3 Family 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-3F",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 10,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "80a0c5c9-83fb-4f38-a3f2-349d174b58e6",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 3 Single + 1 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-3 S1",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 11,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "427a74d6-9df8-4e3a-b84b-29c006af2203",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 3 Single 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-3S",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 12,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "6323d281-8f1b-4bd0-9ac3-7c624fb8046a",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 4 Family 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-4F",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 13,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "eb51b5e5-2cb1-4c99-96f1-c709120c3cb4",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 4 Single + 1 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-4 S1",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 14,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "0a390297-e77e-44b9-bb8a-ae39f25129f0",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary DOC Plan 4 Single 99078299.doc",
            FormNumber = "DOC-99078299-4S",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 15,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "3ec07cc2-7228-49b3-b25f-b77450c61cd7",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 1 Family 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 16,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "dfb57cd5-ba6a-43d0-b66e-bd22b5cca595",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 1 Single + Child 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 17,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "be9260b6-8191-4a25-bda3-0d5a39049714",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 1 Single + Spouse 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 18,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "c5d68d60-a0c0-4dd4-9d7b-8beeaa92b195",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 1 Single 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 19,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "b83d2f96-863a-4ab4-a665-f239b2dcf927",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 2 Family 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 20,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "0608d614-fa94-40bb-9d02-13d77aa9d116",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 2 Single + Child 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 21,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "84022349-3f83-414e-8636-dfcad5b68b2e",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 2 Single + Spouse 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 22,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "85169edb-b2b7-4633-9036-4090daabd924",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 2 Single 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 23,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "c4b9cfd6-23db-4727-a05c-d8e3b897b28e",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 3 Family 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 24,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "02de6cb2-0db4-4b90-8a6c-c87a1d5648ef",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 3 Single + Child 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 25,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "87710917-e9b2-45e9-be24-dfa1ebbebc9c",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 3 Single + Spouse 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 26,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "aac423ea-8c22-401c-96b2-9b241f34c87c",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 3 Single 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 27,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "beb27c9f-2c1f-4b30-a1bc-f5e0c76941a1",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 4 Family 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 28,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "1fff7ab9-34a3-420b-96af-1872a14c464b",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 4 Single + Child 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 29,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "c9f87921-72a1-4cd5-91a5-91942da063fd",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 4 Single + Spouse 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 30,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "0ed44913-35b6-4233-9367-bd023fcac0a2",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP DOC Plan 4 Single 99078298.doc",
            FormNumber = "ASHIP5000-DOC RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 31,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "e75b63fd-1a7e-40e7-9c0e-482684668f12",
            DocumentName = "CI DOC Plan 1 Primary + Sp 99078320.docx",
            FormNumber = "Form 44-10-0672 (Ed. 03-14) RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 32,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "407a0587-3b06-4a7a-a55f-b354b5f41e3b",
            DocumentName = "CI DOC Plan 1 Primary 99078320.docx",
            FormNumber = "Form 44-10-0672 (Ed. 03-14) RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 33,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "59928258-c18b-4421-ac64-a37b484405e5",
            DocumentName = "CI DOC Plan 2 Primary + Sp 99078320.docx",
            FormNumber = "Form 44-10-0672 (Ed. 03-14) RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 34,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "9782f1a3-2f44-4d01-b2f8-25e894afaf5a",
            DocumentName = "CI DOC Plan 2 Primary 99078320.docx",
            FormNumber = "Form 44-10-0672 (Ed. 03-14) RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 35,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "20ccd21b-2ee4-421e-bbe3-c38d60802400",
            DocumentName = "CI DOC Plan 3 Primary + Sp 99078320.docx",
            FormNumber = "Form 44-10-0672 (Ed. 03-14) RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 36,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "e72db228-fc77-4d19-b681-e3e0a0ad3a95",
            DocumentName = "CI DOC Plan 3 Primary 99078320.docx",
            FormNumber = "Form 44-10-0672 (Ed. 03-14) RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 37,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "0d69aedf-53e2-4105-a6bb-3a976d8bf366",
            DocumentName = "CI DOC Plan 4 Primary + Sp 99078320.docx",
            FormNumber = "Form 44-10-0672 (Ed. 03-14) RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 38,
            DocumentTypeUID = 4,
            DocumentToken = "f5e3a49c-2eb6-425d-91ee-ed8e5ed29b89",
            DocumentName = "CI DOC Plan 4 Primary 99078320.docx",
            FormNumber = "Form 44-10-0672 (Ed. 03-14) RI",
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 39,
            DocumentTypeUID = 1,
            DocumentToken = "33274185-c673-44ed-b8e5-2a10b6d34263",
            DocumentName = "Crescent Medical Bridge Privacy Policy.docx",
            FormNumber = null,
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = true,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 40,
            DocumentTypeUID = 7,
            DocumentToken = "ab2395f5-dbe5-405c-9bc4-c0e90166e55f",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Basic Policy 99078426.pdf",
            FormNumber = null,
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = false,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 41,
            DocumentTypeUID = 7,
            DocumentToken = "e2a59a6e-50e9-4dcd-9e40-8ced64a30568",
            DocumentName = "AD&D AME Voluntary Policy 99078299.pdf",
            FormNumber = null,
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = false,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 42,
            DocumentTypeUID = 7,
            DocumentToken = "35f7384f-d268-4762-af20-1194e9b95213",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP Policy Blanket 99078349.pdf",
            FormNumber = null,
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = false,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 43,
            DocumentTypeUID = 7,
            DocumentToken = "5c60fcfd-1b78-47e4-b5af-f2e4f15ed95d",
            DocumentName = "ASHIP Voluntary Policy 99078298.pdf",
            FormNumber = null,
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = false,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 44,
            DocumentTypeUID = 7,
            DocumentToken = "caca3175-06f0-4e40-8c7a-e0e1ba937051",
            DocumentName = "CI Policy 99078337 embedded.pdf",
            FormNumber = null,
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = false,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        ,
        new Document
        {
            DocumentUID = 45,
            DocumentTypeUID = 7,
            DocumentToken = "e66f05b0-61e3-4662-885d-576993a9ed6f",
            DocumentName = "CI Vol Policy 99078320.pdf",
            FormNumber = null,
            IsActive = true,
            SendToParticipant = false,
            RequiresTransformation = false
        }
        );

    }
}
}
```

Initial Seed Records in Database:

[InitialSeedData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhPqg.png)

Seed Data after subsequent updata-database command:

[SubsequentSeedData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MACt8.png)

---

Update:

I added the following code to the top of the SeedDatabase Method:

```
  if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

This allowed me to debug the seed method being called during the update-database command.

The underlying issue appears to be the fact that at some point, a snap shot was taken of the data inside my model and is being stored somewhere in the code. This snap shot of data is already in the context before the seed method is called initially.

I am using AddOrUpdate extension and for some reason even though the object is different from the snapshot data, the seed model data is not changed on the first call.

Regardless, the work around is to simply to clear the Documents table at the top of the seed method. This obviously just sets the records to exactly what I want them to be, so problem solved for now.

Comment: can you post your seed code?